# How do I add the value of a variable to an array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

```
int [][] arr = new int [1][9];
```

column 1/2 (arr[0][0-9]), row 1 to 10 is filled with numbers.

I have the following variable that changes its value in each loop in a for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){

int value = 1;
```

Different if statemts are ,depending on the corresponding number within arr, adding +1 /+2 or +5 to the variables value. (already working)

I now want to take each value assigned to the corresponding number in arr and put it in a new array. (That´s where Im stuck)

Here's what I tried:

```
 int [] arr2 = new int [9];
 calcNumbr(arr2);
 for (int k = 0; k<arr2.length; k++){
 arr2[k] = arr2[value];
```

Then I want to add every number within that array to get a sum

```
  int sum = 0;
  sum += t;
  }
```

Comment: Can you include your full current code, and then point out where the problem(s) lie?  It is hard to follow what you are asking in your current question.

Comment: I added some more code. Sadly its forbidden to post everything so I hope thats enough to get what´s the problem.

Comment: Agree with @TimBiegeleisen. Please post full code so it would be much easier to understand your problem and try to fix it. There is no implementation of the method `calcNumbr(arr);` cant be seen so its hard to tell whats wrong etc.

Comment: @Reborn the method isnt´t necessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a value of a variable to an array like this:

```
int value = 100;
int [] arr2 = new int [9];
int k = 0;
arr2[k] = value;
```

Your line `arr2[k] = arr2[value];` from your sample adds the value from position *value* to position *k*.